# 503 server too busy on image and css

Tags: apache2, server, http-status-code-503

I uploaded my website on an apache2 server and some images and css are not loading. I checked the web console and I can see GET 503 (server too busy) error .

[image]

Even when I hit refresh page several times , the images and css not loading will be still there and random.

I tried to upload my website in another apache2 server and everything were working fine. What kind of setting could cause a 503 (server too busy) error ?

EDIT : My .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.org$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.org/$1 [R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^./]+)$ /$1.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Can be caused by a rewrite rule that effectively creates a loop. Are you able to check error logs on the server?

Comment: I added my rewrite rule of the .htaccess file.

Comment: this post suggests the other server has too little RAM memory allogated ( http://serverfault.com/questions/579413/server-too-busy-after-moving-to-fcgid). Are the servers identical?

Comment: Is the same .htaccess file used on both the working and not working servers? Where you able to see what errors were reported on the server side?